# Chrome text not wrapping in table when using ::before

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome, I am seeing text overflow instead of wrap in table cells when using `::before` on content inside the cell. It seems like `::before` is the trigger, everything will wrap as expected without it. I don't see this in Firefox or IE/Edge.

Below is a very simplified example. In the system I am working in, I am not able to change the HTML, only the CSS.

Using `display: inline-block` on the `label` fixes the wrapping, but it makes the green box no longer appear inline (the wrapped line will align to the right of the green box instead of to the left). I am trying to find some way to make Chrome simply wrap as other browsers do.

### Firefox and IE/Edge

[image: Firefox and IE/Edge]

### Chrome

[image]

```css
table {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label {
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

label::before {
  border: 1px solid green;
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>text A</label></td>
      <td><label>text B</label></td>
      <td><label>text C</label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why making the pseudo element positon:absolute? a simple inline-block will do the trick

Comment: As for why it is absolute positioned, this is just a simplified example with the minimum to trigger the problem. I need the absolute positioning so I can put the green box (which is really something more complex) into an exact spot.

Comment: There is a bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Chrome and they have fixed it. The solution is to use the latest version of Chrome.

More info at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925493.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I mixed up the browsers. Now I'm sure I was in Chrome, same version as yours:

```
label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[Same PEN updated](https://codepen.io/sebaLinares/pen/MLaOWL?editors=1100)

Comment: changed ::before for an ::after btw

Comment: I saw, but it might be too late. I didn't down-vote you, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Just added display:table

EDITED: Changed label:before and added display:inline-block

thanks [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for your contribution.

```css
table {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;

}

label {
  position: relative;
  display:table;
}

label::before {
  border: 1px solid green;
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>text A</label></td>
      <td><label>text B</label></td>
      <td><label>text C</label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't look the same as it does in FFox.There is additional padding on the left after the break.

Comment: I Edited the answer, please check it now

Comment: no need position:relative since top and left are 0 (they can also be removed)

Comment: you can also get rid of break-word

Comment: Why the `display: table` on the `label`? Seems to complicate things.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again

Comment: @AndyHoffman display:table works like width:fit-content, but is more generic

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer mostly involves *removing* code, which is my favorite sort of answer.

1. Remove the base `label` styles completely
2. Modify the `:before` so that it has default (static) positioning. Because it's no longer absolutely positioned, we can also remove the positioning rules.
3. I made the `:before` `inline-block` so that it would respond to vertical alignment and keep the `label` text properly aligned.

```css
table {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

label:before {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>text A</label></td>
    <td><label>text B</label></td>
    <td><label>text C</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS Weight Loss**

Before: 22 lines

After: 16 lines

https://jsfiddle.net/tn7hbv8z/3/